# How to substitute a list of patterns with a different one?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I try to change in a file some word by others using `sed` or `awk`.

I have 1 `fileA` like this:

```
((A,(B,(C,D))),(E));  
((A,B),C),D),(E));
```

and a second `fileB` with the patterns to change:

```
A (foo,bar,foox,barn,foon) 
B (cat,dog,sheep,abc)  
C (cadd,dget,vdhfu,dssu,dfhty,dueit)  
D (cdfte,shdgt,cdht,ddht,ddh)  
E (cdc,addge)
```

I want to substitute in my `fileA` the values `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E` by the one in the pattern file.

---

**My attempt:**

```
while read n k; do sed -i.bak "s/$k/$n/g" fileA; done < fileB
```

Comment: What went wrong? please put the error/incorrect result in your question.

Comment: there is no change, the file is the same. 
I also tried `sed "s/$k/$n/g"`
and `sed 's/"$k"/"$n"/g'`

maybe sed is not the best tool?

Comment: which one will be substituted to, the whole list e.g. (foo,bar,..) or any one element only?

Comment: the whole list. Can be very long for some list. The format is `(Abcd_xyz_x1,Efgh_abcs_y2,Mnho_kjhu_b2)`
no space in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Perl also..

```
$ cat nico_fileA
((A,(B,(C,D))),(E));
((A,B),C),D),(E));

$ cat nico_fileB
A (foo,bar,foox,barn,foon)
B (cat,dog,sheep,abc)
C (cadd,dget,vdhfu,dssu,dfhty,dueit)
D (cdfte,shdgt,cdht,ddht,ddh)
E (cdc,addge)

$ perl -pe ' BEGIN { %kv=map{chomp;split} qx(cat nico_fileB) } s/([A-E])/$kv{$1}/g ' nico_fileA
(((foo,bar,foox,barn,foon),((cat,dog,sheep,abc),((cadd,dget,vdhfu,dssu,dfhty,dueit),(cdfte,shdgt,cdht,ddht,ddh)))),((cdc,addge)));
(((foo,bar,foox,barn,foon),(cat,dog,sheep,abc)),(cadd,dget,vdhfu,dssu,dfhty,dueit)),(cdfte,shdgt,cdht,ddht,ddh)),((cdc,addge)));

$
```

Comment: glad to hear that.. have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

```
sed "$(sed 's/^\([^ ]*\) \(.*\)$/s#\1#\2#g/' fileB)" fileA
```

The inner `sed` transforms the lines from `fileB` into `s/<pattern>/<pattern>/g`.
Then the next sed is run with the arguments as the output from the first.

For the input file `fileB` the inner `sed` will print:

```
s#A#(foo,bar,foox,barn,foon)#g
s#B#(cat,dog,sheep,abc)#g
s#C#(cadd,dget,vdhfu,dssu,dfhty,dueit)#g
s#D#(cdfte,shdgt,cdht,ddht,ddh)#g
s#E#(cdc,addge)#g
```

which can be passed to the outer `sed` to execute.

Tested on [jdoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/test-bash-shell-script-online) with the following:

```
cat <<EOF >fileA
((A,(B,(C,D))),(E));  
((A,B),C),D),(E)); 
EOF

cat <<EOF >fileB
A (foo,bar,foox,barn,foon)
B (cat,dog,sheep,abc)
C (cadd,dget,vdhfu,dssu,dfhty,dueit)
D (cdfte,shdgt,cdht,ddht,ddh)
E (cdc,addge)
EOF

sed "$(sed 's/^\([^ ]*\) \(.*\)$/s#\1#\2#g/' fileB)" fileA
```

I get this output:

```
(((foo,bar,foox,barn,foon),((cat,dog,sheep,abc),((cadd,dget,vdhfu,dssu,dfhty,dueit),(cdfte,shdgt,cdht,ddht,ddh)))),((cdc,addge)));  
(((foo,bar,foox,barn,foon),(cat,dog,sheep,abc)),(cadd,dget,vdhfu,dssu,dfhty,dueit)),(cdfte,shdgt,cdht,ddht,ddh)),((cdc,addge)));
```

Answer (score 1):

One the things to worry about in this situation is if one of the replacement *values* contains one of the replacment *keys*.  For example, if you are looking at the original text

```
AfooB
```

and replacing with

```
A B
B C
```

You want to end up with `BfooC`, but if you do successive full text replacments:

```
sed -i 's/A/B/g' file
sed -i 's/B/C/g' file
```

you'll get `CfooC`.

For this reason, a character by character approach is safest:

- look at each position in each line starting at index 0
- if any of the keys matches at this point in the string, replace with the replacement for that key
- increment the index and repeat

The Tcl language does this with its [`string map`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M34) command. Here's a bash implementation:

```
# read fileB into an associative array
# keep track of the keys separately so we can be sure to process them in order
declare -A replacements
declare -a keys

while read -r key value; do
    replacements[$key]=$value
    keys+=("$key")
done < fileB

# process fileA
while IFS= read -r line; do
    new=""
    i=0
    while (( i < ${#line} )); do
        replaced=false
        for key in "${keys[@]}"; do
            len=${#key}
            if [[ ${line:i:len} == "$key" ]]; then
                new+=${replacements[$key]}
                replaced=true
                (( i += len ))
                break
            fi
        done
        # did we find a replacement at this point in the string?
        # if not, append the character to the new string.
        if ! $replaced; then
            new+=${line:i:1}
            (( i += 1 ))
        fi
    done
    echo "$new"
done < fileA
```

resulting in

```
(((foo,bar,foox,barn,foon),((cat,dog,sheep,abc),((cadd,dget,vdhfu,dssu,dfhty,dueit),(cdfte,shdgt,cdht,ddht,ddh)))),((cdc,addge)));
(((foo,bar,foox,barn,foon),(cat,dog,sheep,abc)),(cadd,dget,vdhfu,dssu,dfhty,dueit)),(cdfte,shdgt,cdht,ddht,ddh)),((cdc,addge)));
```

Comment: This works in this instance, because there are only distinct keys, right? If the keys were, for example "F", "FO", "FOO", it would not check for "FOO" or "FO" before it replaced "F", depending on the order of the keys, right?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, tested only with GNU `awk` only.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=a[$i]?a[$i]:$i}} 1' FS=" "  Input_fileB  FS="" OFS=  Input_fileA
```

Output will be as follows.

```
(((foo,bar,foox,barn,foon),((cat,dog,sheep,abc),((cadd,dget,vdhfu,dssu,dfhty,dueit),(cdfte,shdgt,cdht,ddht,ddh)))),((cdc,addge)));  
(((foo,bar,foox,barn,foon),(cat,dog,sheep,abc)),(cadd,dget,vdhfu,dssu,dfhty,dueit)),(cdfte,shdgt,cdht,ddht,ddh)),((cdc,addge)));
```

Comment: @Nico64, could you please check this one once and let  me know then?

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert `fileB` lines into substitution commands(as suggested in @KamilCuk's answer) and process the output as a file by using [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) with the sed `-f` flag:

```
sed -f <(sed -E 's#([^ ]*) (.*)#s/\1/\2/#' fileB) fileA
```